# Only half of screen used and mouse artifacts displayed

Tags: video, lightdm, intel, acer

This may be a duplicate, but I have not found a solution as yet.
When I boot the computer, only the bottom half of the login screen is displayed on the top portion of the computer screen. Dragging the mouse around the screen causes artifacts to be displayed. I am able to log in, but still only see the bottom half of the display shown on the top half of the screen.

```
 Computer: Acer Asprie AO751
 OS: Ubuntu 12.4 LTS
 Video: Intel system controller hub (schpoulson) graphics controller
 Video driver in use: GMA 500
 Grub: "...i915.modeset=1 quiet splash acpi=force"
```

If I log in then logout and back in immediately, I will get the full screen display as I should. If I switch to tty <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and run `sudo restart lightdm` I can switch back to the gui and will have the full screen display. I have the same issue using either the netbook display or external display.

Answer (score 0):

Am having exactly the same problem (same model, plus I also get a black screen on start-up).

Anyway I found this:

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/ubuntu-12-04-gma500-poulsbo-boot-options/

Which describes the exact same problem. Iḿ still working through the solutions, but it might be worth checking out.